# How can I use `using namespace Eigen` in an RCppEigen based R package?

Tags: r, rcpp

The C++ code in my package has `using namespace Eigen;` but this doesn't get put at the top of the auto-generated `RcppExports.cpp`. As a result compilation fails complaining `MatrixXd` etc is not recognized. I can manually add `using namespace Eigen;` to `RcppExports.cpp` and everything works fine, but this make the workflow pretty painful.

Is there some way to configure `Rcpp` to automatically add `using namespace Eigen;` to `RcppExports.cpp`?

Comment: For interfaces like function signatures I recommend to fully qualify and use _e.g._ `Eigen::MatrixXd`.  Look what other packages do.  Also, see the Rcpp Attributes vignette about the `mypackage_types.h` header (where `mypackage` gets replaced with your package name).

Comment: Thanks Dirk, `mypackage_types.h` is exactly what I want.

Comment: Also, note that in general, `using namespace foo` can lead to headaches down the road. See [c++- Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4408538)